# How to parse openweather data with simpledate format

Tags: java, date, parsing, simpledateformat

I receive date and time from openweather api in such format `"dt":1489602000"`, I don't know what that mean. I want to receive something like this `"2014-07-23 09:00:00"` How can I transform it using SimpleDateFormat

Comment: Based on the docs *"dt Time of data calculation, unix, UTC"* - I would suggest that the value is actually the number of seconds since the Unix Epoch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String transformedDate = new SimpleDateFormat("H:mm  dd MMM yy").format(new Date(yourTime*1000));
```

[Customize your date format like there](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/simpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: Adding a brief explanation of how your code works would be helpful to both the asker and future readers.

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), and `java.text.SimpleTextFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.